# SF Symbols usage restriction

Tags: ios, appstore-approval, sf-symbols

I recently came across SF Symbols. For some of the images, I do see usage restrictions listed for that image which says something like this: "This symbol may not be modified and may only be used to refer to Apple’s iCloud service."

Does this mean that if my app is not using iCloud services, but if I use this image (let's say to show network disconnect) in my app, then will my app get rejected in app store?

[image]

Comment: ”will my app get rejected in app store” is off-topic on stackoverflow, as explained in the info for the appstore-approval tag. Anyway, you should be safe if you use wifi.slash to indicate lack  of a network connection.